# Downward Lowenheim-Skolem and the Theory of Infinite-Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $T$ be the theory of infinite dimensional vector spaces. It seems to me that by downward Lowenheim-Skolem we should be able to produce a countable model for this theory. But that means that there is a vector space which is countable with infinite dimension, which ought to be impossible. Could anyone explain where I have gone wrong?

Comment: The theory of infinite dimensional vector spaces over what field?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I realized that the term "theory of vector spaces" makes it sound like I am fixing a field and adding its elements as constants, which is not quite what I intended. I was thinking of a universe consisting of both elements of the vector space and field. Add unary relations $V, F$ denoting membership in the vector space and the field respectively. Then, we would be able to formulate the field/vector space axioms using these predicates.

Comment: @TimothyZhou If you want to do it like that, then I think you need to do this in a multi-sorted setting. One issue you would run into like doing it like this is that you want to be able to say that $\forall x(1\cdot x=x)$, which would mean that $\cdot$ can take in both scalars and vectors in either argument and I don't think you want this to happen.

Comment: @TimothyZhou Yeah, my comment and answer were a bit overly dogmatic... one could take a many-sorted approach. One would still need to think about whether "infinite-dimensional" could be axiomatized, and of course it's a bit tangential to the main issue here.

Comment: There are in fact countable vector spaces of infinite dimension, and if you insist, over an infinite field. For example, the vector space of polynomials of rational coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple notes on "the theory of infinite-dimensional vector spaces":

- For the usual single-sorted, first-order treatment of vector spaces, scalar multiplication is represented as a family of function symbols, one for each element of the field. So there is not one theory of vector spaces, but rather a theory of vector spaces over $F,$ for each field $F.$
- Even if we fix a field $F$, there is not necessarily a such thing as the theory of *infinite-dimensional* vector spaces, since this is not necessarily an axiomatizable class. In fact this is the case if and only if $F$ is finite (in which case it coincides with the class of *infinite* vector spaces, which is axiomatizable).

Note that since there is a function symbol for each scalar, the size of the language is the same as the size of the field. So, e.g. the theory of real vector spaces has an uncountable language, so LS does not imply there are no countable models (and if we preclude the trivial vector space, there aren't).

As mentioned in the comments, we can also use two-sorted first-order logic to axiomatize vector spaces, in which case "the theory of infinite-dimensional vector spaces" makes sense.

All that said, the main issue was already addressed by Mark Saving in his answer: It's just wrong that an infinite-dimensional vector space can't be countable. Consider the direct sum of countably many copies of any finite field.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared things up for me. Minor note: there is a typo in the example in your last paragraph, that direct sum is uncountable (I believe you meant to give the example legionwhale did in the comments).

Comment: @TimothyZhou the direct sum is the same example. (Think you’re thinking of the direct product.)

Comment: There is a 2-sorted theory of an infinite-dimensional vector space over a field. But you are correct that for a fixed field, there is no first-order theory of an infinite-dimensional vector space over that field (unless the field is finite). I should have caught that in my own answer.

Comment: @MarkSaving Yes, if I'd realized that I may have not bothered to write an answer, since I wouldn't have felt the need to add anything. This was touched on in the comments below the main post, but I am not familiar with that approach and wasn't sure offhand if 'infinite dimensional' was axiomatizable there. But now that you tell me it is, I see that you can just add a countably infinite set of vector constants and write down a schema saying they're all linearly independent.

Comment: @MarkSaving (Actually, scratch the part about adding constant symbols... makes no sense. But anyway, you can write down a schema saying there are arbitrarily large sets of LI vectors.)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which field you are using. Let’s say you’re using a countable field $k$ (since otherwise even a 1-D vector space is uncountable).

In this case, a vector space with countably infinite dimension is countable. In particular, suppose $V$ is a vector space with basis $\{v_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then we can easily show that $V = \bigcup\limits_{j \in \mathbb{N}} span(v_0, \ldots, v_j)$. Each vector space $span(v_0, \ldots, v_j)$ is finite-dimensional, hence countable. And the countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Take a finite field like $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which is obviously countable, and consider the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_2^\omega$. This has a countable basis, but an uncountable amount of elements. I don't think your statement about the union of the spans is true.

Comment: @TimothyZhou Your space doesn't have a countable basis. Bear in mind that spans refer to finite sums of elements in the set. One example of a countable vector space (with a countable basis) would be the vector subspace of all elements with only finitely many non-zero elements.

Comment: I think I am missing something basic, sorry. By $\mathbb{Z}_2^\omega$ I mean the direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ with itself countably infinite many times. Then shouldn't the set $\{(1, 0, 0, ...), (0, 1, 0, ...), ...\}$ be a countable basis?

Comment: @TimothyZhou No. You can't express the vector of all ones as a linear combination.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: @TimothyZhou Yes, easy to accidentally import infinite sums in simple examples, but that requires more structure than just vector space. c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis